# I've added a css on one of my webform but it only works in my master page and not on specific webform

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, master-pages

I've added a CSS on one of my web forms but it only works in my master page and not on a specific web form.

This is one of my web forms but the icon I added is not appearing on the site.i also have CSS on my master page. don't know why CSS is not appearing on this web form.

```
<link href="../Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
    <td><%# Eval("Email") %></td>
    <td> <%# Eval("DateRegistered", "{0: MMMM dd, yyyy}") %></td>
    <td> <%# Eval("Status")%></td>
    <td>
      <a href='CustomerDetails.aspx?id=<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>'
         class="btn btn-xs"
         title ="View Details"
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>

      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I would check the CSS link in the browser to see where its pointing to/from.

Comment: downloaded css in NuGet Package and drag the css in webform

Answer (score 0):

Create a new theme in your WebApplication and then set the property Theme="MyTheme" in your page.

Check out this link:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a0a81e/3/